# Uniqueness of solutions to $u_{tt} - c^{2}u_{xxxx} + au_{t} = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The problem I am working on is to show that there is a unique compactly supported solution to the PDE $u_{tt} - c^{2}u_{xxxx} + au_{t} = 0$, $(x, t) \in \mathbb{R} \times [0, \infty)$ with $u(x, 0)= \phi(x)$ and $u_{t}(x, 0) = \psi(x)$ where $\phi, \psi$ are smooth and compactly supported.

Suppose I had 2 solutions $u_{1}$ and $u_{2}$ for the above equation. Then let $v = u_{1} - u_{2}$. Thus $v_{tt} - c^{2}v_{xxxx} + av_{t} = 0$, $v(x, 0) = 0$, $v_{t}(x,0) = 0$. I think if I can define the correct energy, I'll be able to solve the problem.

If I let $E(t) := \frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}u_{t}^{2} - c^{2}u_{xx}^{2}\, dx$, then I can show that $E'(t) \leq 0$ for all $t > 0$. The problem is $E(t)$ is not necessarily $\geq 0$. Is there a way to use another energy function to prove uniquness?

Comment: I suppose by compactly supported you mean compactly supported for every finite time interval, i.e, for $0 \le t \le T$, for every $T$, right?

Comment: Oh, and do you also assume $a>0$?

Comment: @LukasGeyer: Yes to both of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help. But if you use Fourier transform on the system, you obtain a Sturm-Liouville problem, namely:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \left(e^{at}\hat u_t\right) = c^2 e^{at}t^4\hat u\\
\hat u(\xi, 0) = \hat \phi(\xi) \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \hat u_t(\xi, 0) = \hat \psi(\xi)
\end{equation}

I believe the compactness of functions $\psi$ and $\phi$ ensures that it is a regular Sturm-Liouville problem, while their smoothness ensures uniqueness of Fourier Transform. But whether a unique solution exists or not, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that there is a sign mistake in the problem statement. Indeed, up to a sign change, this PDE models the dynamic deflection of a damped [Euler-Bernoulli beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory). To show this, we define the Lagrangian density $\mathcal{L} = K - V$ with $K = \tfrac12 (u_t)^2$ and $V = \tfrac12 c^2 (u_{xx})^2$ representing the kinetic energy and the potential energy. Furthermore, we introduce the Rayleigh dissipation function $D = \tfrac12 a (u_t)^2$. The corresponding quasi-[variational problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) leads to the following equation of motion with non-conservative forces (pseudo Euler-Lagrange equation) $$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u} - \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_t} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial u_{xx}} = \frac{\partial D}{\partial u_t} ,
$$ i.e., $$
u_{tt} + c^2 u_{xxxx} = -a u_t ,
$$
which is similar to our initial PDE (up to the sign in front of the fourth-order spatial derivative). This remark leads to considering instead the non-negative Hamiltonian energy $$
E(t) = \int_{\Bbb R} (K + V)\, dx \geq 0
$$
such that $$
\begin{aligned}
E'(t) &= \int_{\Bbb R} \left(u_tu_{tt} + c^2u_{xx}u_{xxt}\right) dx \\
&= c^2 \int_{\Bbb R} \left(-u_tu_{xxxx} + u_{xx}u_{xxt}\right) dx - a \int_{\Bbb R} (u_t)^2 dx \\
&= c^2 \int_{\Bbb R} u_{xxx} \left(u_{tx} - u_{xt}\right) dx - a \int_{\Bbb R} (u_t)^2 dx \\
&= - a \int_{\Bbb R} (u_t)^2 dx \leq 0 .
\end{aligned}
$$ where the PDE, integration by parts and the equality of mixed partials were used. With this definition, the energy method can be applied in the usual way (see also [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2954040/418542)).