# Energy methods for Euler - Bernoulli beam equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove the uniqueness of solutions of Euler - Bernoulli beam equation:

> $\left\{\begin{matrix}
> u_{tt}+a^{2}u_{xxxx}=0, &0<x<L \\ 
> u(x,0)=0, &0\le x\le L\\
> u_{t}(x,0)=0, &0\le x\le L 
> \end{matrix}\right.$

My attempt: I multiply the equation by $u_{t}$, then integrating and defining the energy of the equation $$E(t)=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{L}[u_{t}^{2}+a^{2}u_{xx}^{2}]dx.$$
However, $\dfrac{dE}{dt}=a^{2}\left[u_{xt}u_{xx}-u_{t}u_{xxx}\right]\Big|_{0}^{L}$ so we only have $E'(0)=0$ and now I don't know how to prove that $E(t)$ is constant. It seems like the energy functional should be different but I haven't figured out yet.

Answer (score 1):

Using the equality of mixed partial derivatives, integration by parts and the PDE itself, we have indeed $\frac{\text d}{\text d t}E =a^2[u_{tx}u_{xx}-u_{t}u_{xxx}]_0^L$. This derivative is equal to zero if ad hoc boundary conditions are applied. Then, the energy method provides uniqueness. But here, boundary conditions are missing.

Comment: My professor told me that this problem was wrong, only initial conditions were not enough. He assumed that the beam was either clamped or simply supported or free and now the energy method works.

Comment: @vutuanhien total ageeement with your professor!